# Is Stripe Checking Customer Card or Source is Valid, After I changed it?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

My question is Stripe handling customer card is valid or not. Do I have to try my own 1$ payment. And if stripe checking it how I will get informed. I am always using 424242.. test card soo it always saves card succesfuly.

Answer (score 0):

4242 4242 4242 4242 is a VISA test card that charges a card in the test scenario. There are plenty of edge cases and failed card payments that you could try out. They provide different card number for this

For more information please follow Stripe's documentation

https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Comment: Thanks for answer. So stripe is checking the card everytime ? Even if its not a charge. For example while saving card to an existing customer without payment.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe runs a $0/$1 authorization with the bank when you create a customer or a card. This ensures the card is valid upfront and if it isn't the customer or card creation would fail.

Comment: That's what I want to hear. Appreciate that!